# Transformer Efficiency

Tags: electromagnetism

Can we convert magnetic flux into electric current via transducer or any other device like that? According to me the transformer flux which is lost during the transfer of magnetic flux from 1 coil to 2 ,can be conserved or converted into electricity which can be used to light a lamp near a transformer.

Comment: What is the efficiency of a well-designed transformer?

Comment: sir, does any magnetic field come outside of the transformer ?

Answer (score 0):

It may be that a 'probe' coil in the vicinity of a transformer will, if orientated correctly, have a small emf induced in it because some escaped alternating flux is linked with it, but the emf will be too small to light a lamp, even, I'd guess, an led. Jon Custer's comment (above) is relevant to this attempted answer.